# Index Match return list with one criteria - non VBA

Tags: excel, list, indexing, match

I want to return a subset of column B based on column A. In this example I want all the names from column B to be in column D based on column A being equal to "Smith"

I have tried something like `{INDEX($B$2:$B$8<>$D$2:D2, MATCH("Smith",$A$2:$A$8, 0))}`

```
    col A   col B       col D
2   Smith   Alice       Alice
3   James   Jay         Betty
4   Smith   Betty       Julia
5   Robert  James       
6   Rose    Matt        
7   Smith   Julia       
8   Johnson Tom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **C2** enter the **array formula**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:B$8,SMALL((IF(A$2:A$8="Smith",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A$2:A$8))))),ROWS($1:1)),1),"")
```

and copy down:
[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!